# How do i create a Xna 4.0 Creating BoundyBox

Tags: xna, c#, bounding-boxes

I understand what other people have done and when creating it myself it just seems to go wrong or the version is different so doesn't work in first place. Any easy code for this?

Comment: Please provide more details, the code you have tried e.t.c. Not very helpful at the moment.

Comment: It's easy -- you just have to make that one change to that one bit of code you didn't provide any details about.

Answer (score 1):

We need more details to be able to help you with your code. However, you can look at this tutorial and see if it helps.

Please edit your post with more details!

http://www.toymaker.info/Games/XNA/html/xna_bounding_box.html

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that website ( http://www.toymaker.info/Games/XNA/html/xna_bounding_box.html ) and it the m_transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] is giving me an error since m_transforms isnt defined